# Difference between 'tf.divide' and '/'

Tags: tensorflow

I was normalizing stuffs where it was required to divide a 56x56 (let's say T) tensor by 56 x 1 (let's say W) tensor. Everything was perfect.

So what I did was use `tf.divide(T , W)` and access the first element it gave me some weird answer while the expected was around 1. But when I used simply do `T / W` , the answer was 1. Why is that so?

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example? Thank you.